# Changing color of an anchor's title

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change the title color for anchor tags which are below `container` class.

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[title]').colorTip({color:'yellow'});
});
```

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="http://tutorialzine.com/" title="title only here.">congue</a> 
</div>
```

It doesn't appear to change the color. Any advice?

Comment: $(".container > a[title]").colorTip (..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
$('[title]').colorTip({color:'yellow'});
```

to:

```
$('div.container > a[title]').colorTip({color:'yellow'});
```

The `div.container > a[title]` means only select an anchor with a title attribute that is a child of a div with the container class.